# R: last argument in elipsis

Tags: r

I have a function `f` that takes three arguments, and returns the last one. For example:

```
f <- function(x,y,z){
    return(z)
}
f(11,22,33) #yields 33
```

However, later on I may have more/less than three arguments, so I want to create a function `g` that returns the last argument of `...`

```
g <- function(...){
    #return final argument in '...'
}

g(11,22) #should yield 22
g(11,22,33,44,'abc') #should yield 'abc'
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

I've looked at existing posts on using `...`, but they all seem to use it to pass all the arguments to another function (which is not what I'm trying to do).

I could just make the argument into a vector, and return the last element, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `...length` and `...elt` like this:

```
f <- function(...) ...elt(...length())
f(11, 12, 13)
## [1] 13
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
g <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  if (length(dots)) dots[[length(dots)]]
}

g(11,22)
# [1] 22

g(11,22,33,44,'abc')
# [1] "abc"

g()  # returns nothing, NULL invisibly
```

I often choose to assign to `dots` or similar in the function and then deal with it, though that can be both good and bad. If you want to pass the args on to other functions, then you can still use `...` as before (or you can use `do.call(..)`, though that's not your question). One side-effect is that by doing this, the `...` are *evaluated*, which though generally fine, in some corner-cases this evaluation may be too soon.

A demonstration:

```r
g(stop("quux"), "abc")
# Error in g(stop("quux"), "abc") : quux
```

If you want to avoid early evaluation of other args, you can use `match.call`:

```r
g <- function(...){
  cl <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
  if (length(cl) > 1) cl[[length(cl)]]
}

g()  # nothing

g(1)
# [1] 1

g(stop("quux"), "abc")
# [1] "abc"
```